# Sharing an old (never used) Phd Proposal with another student

Tags: phd

Can I share a Phd proposal that I wrote five years ago with a potential student, who is currently applying for a PhD? Please note that I never used my proposal to apply to a PhD program till this moment? The person asked me to share it wants a real example of a proposal. But I feel it is my effort. Is it ok to share it? Thanks

Comment: Why do you have any doubt?

Comment: The setting is unclear. Are you a student? Did you write this proposal? If yes, it's yours, why do you ask? Are you worried it will be plagiarised and deprive you of your chance of doing the research? Are you concerned that the other student will present it as their own?

Answer (score -2):

If you are applying with that proposal, then you should not share it. How would you feel if they present it better than you and get a post while you don't? It is your work, present it and use it yourself.

Why not offer to read and help them edit their proposal? But let them write their own.